# What would the deploy.sh file look like for Gitlab CI?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In the Docker registry docs on the [gitlab Site](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/05/23/gitlab-container-registry/) they give an example where the deploy stage has:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ./deploy.sh
  only:
    - master
```

What would the deploy.sh file look like? In either pseudo code or real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only an example on how configure Gitlab to run a custom script that may have large complexity, so it is better to put it in a script.

The deployment commands depends on your specific architecture and platform.

For instance:

1. Push the builder docker image to docker hub or your private registry
2. Trigger a swarm or kubernetes deployment

Answer (score 3):

There is my deploy stage:

```
deploy_to_prod_server:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ssh root@example.com ./deploy/be-deploy.sh $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
```

and there is be-deploy.sh:

```
name=$1
cd deploy
rm docker-compose.yml
cp docker-compose.yml.example docker-compose.yml
rpl "__BE-IMAGE__" $name docker-compose.yml
docker stack rm my_be_container_name
docker rmi $name
docker pull $name
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml my_be_container_name
```

Comment: how do you handle a racy CI pipeline, i.e. two pipeline runs where the earlier run finishes later than the later run?  How do you prevent the the newer version not being overwritten by the older version?